# Custom Aggregate in postgres using multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

### Disclaimer: Solution below

I have a set of records from a query with columns `(idx, time, category, weight, distance)`:

- `idx` is an `INTEGER` value describing some sort of relation
- `time` is `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE` that can take (almost) arbitrary values, but each value will be present many times (for every `idx` and `category`)
- `category` is `VARCHAR` and a categorical variable; its values are limited and will recur quite often
- `weight` is `DOUBLE PRECISION`
- `distance` is some precalculated value

The rows can look like the following:

```
(1, '2017-01-01 00:00', 'class_a', 1, 234.5)
(1, '2017-01-01 00:00', 'class_a', 1, 987.1)
(1, '2017-01-01 00:00', 'class_a', 1, 1.23)
(1, '2017-01-01 00:00', 'class_b', 1, 48.5)
(2, '2017-01-01 00:00', 'class_a', 1, 8763.5)
(1, '2017-01-01 00:13', 'class_a', 1, 598.02)
(1, '2017-01-01 00:13', 'class_b', 1, 76.9)
...
(2, '2017-01-27 21:07', 'class_b', 1, 184.0)
```

## What's the question?

I'm seeking for a solution to calculate a custom aggregate on such data, but I can hardly find any instructions or examples on how this is *actually* done (hopefully possible without writing a C extension to postgres).

```
SELECT
  idx, time, category,
  weighted_density(
    value, distance, 10000.0 -- arbitrary 10k is explained below
  ) AS wd
FROM (my rows as shown above)
GROUP BY
  idx, time, category
```

I feel like setting up a custom aggregate (named `WEIGHTED_DENSITY` here) should be the right way to achieve something like the outlined query. My aim is to end up with a result set where the compound `(idx, time, category)` is unique, and its `wd` is calculated using all `weight` and `distance` values from the related rows.

### Disclaimer: Solution below

## What have I tried so far?

First, I was getting the entire rows from the database and calculated the aggregate *off-line* using another program and language (python). But this is quite resource consuming and should be run on the database server instead of the local machine (also to ensure integrity).

Then, I tried setting up a postgres function to calculate the result value using a single row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _gaussian_density(
    IN DOUBLE PRECISION, -- the weight
    IN DOUBLE PRECISION, -- the distance
    IN DOUBLE PRECISION  -- the maximum distance
  ) RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  -- calculate weighted density, using max distance;
  -- this calculation itself doesn't really matter; it's some sort
  -- of density using a cropped gaussian kernel, for those who ask.
  RETURN
    CASE
      WHEN ABS($2) > ABS($3) THEN 0.0
      WHEN ABS($2) <= 0.0 THEN 1.0
      ELSE
        $1 * (
          1.0 / |/ (2.0 * PI())
        ) * POWER(EXP(-1 * (3.0 * ABS($2) / ABS($3))), 2)
        / 0.4
    END;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 10;
```

Also, to make the function available as an aggregate, I tried

```
CREATE AGGREGATE weighted_density(DOUBLE PRECISION, DOUBLE PRECISION)
(
    sfunc = _gaussian_density,
    stype = DOUBLE PRECISION,
    initcond = 0.0
);
```

But that's where I'm stuck, I just can't get it right and it seems I need an example or a little bit of a hint that pushes me into the right direction on how custom aggregates are properly created and made use of.

Cheers to you guys and thanks a lot in advance!

## SOLUTION

Thanks @klin for pointing out that I missed to carry the aggregate state along. Now, this finally works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION _gaussian_density(
    weight FLOAT8,
    distance FLOAT8,
    maxdist FLOAT8
  )
RETURNS FLOAT8
IMMUTABLE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
  DECLARE
    abs_weight FLOAT8;
    abs_distance FLOAT8;
    abs_maxdist FLOAT8;
    dist_weight FLOAT8;
  BEGIN
    -- calculate weighted density, using max distance;
    -- this calculation itself doesn't really matter; it's some sort
    -- of density using a cropped gaussian kernel, for the curious
    abs_weight := ABS(COALESCE(weight, 1.0));
    abs_distance := ABS(COALESCE(distance, 0.0));
    abs_maxdist := ABS(COALESCE(maxdist, 0.0));
    IF abs_distance > abs_maxdist THEN RETURN 0.0; END IF;
    IF abs_distance <= 0.0 THEN RETURN 1.0 * abs_weight; END IF;
    RETURN abs_weight * (
            1.0 / |/ (2.0 * PI())
          ) * POWER(EXP(-1 * (3.0 * abs_distance / abs_maxdist)), 2)
          / 0.4;
  END;
$$;

CREATE FUNCTION _gaussian_statetransition(
    agg_state FLOAT8, -- carry the state!
    weight FLOAT8,
    distance FLOAT8,
    maxdist FLOAT8)
RETURNS FLOAT8
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN
      agg_state + _gaussian_density(weight, distance, maxdist);
  END;
$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE weighted_density(FLOAT8, FLOAT8, FLOAT8)
(
    sfunc = _gaussian_statetransition,
    stype = FLOAT8,
    initcond = 0
);
```

I wanted to be able to still use the density calculation function outside of an aggregate, so I decided to add another function for the *state transition* which in turn employs the function `_gaussian_density`.

The aggregate then defines the state type and its initial state and we're good to go. In order to correctly handle some edge cases, I adapted `_gaussian_density` a bit (also towards dealing with `NULL` values)..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `_gaussian_density()` should depend on the value calculated in the previous step. If in your case this is the first argument `weight` then the initial condition should not be 0, as all next calculations will give zero as a result. I assume that the initial value of `weight` is 1.0:

```
DROP AGGREGATE weighted_density(DOUBLE PRECISION, DOUBLE PRECISION);
CREATE AGGREGATE weighted_density(DOUBLE PRECISION, DOUBLE PRECISION)
(
    sfunc = _gaussian_density,
    stype = DOUBLE PRECISION,
    initcond = 1.0 -- !!
);
```

Note that the aggregate does not use the column `weight` of the table as it is internal-state value, for which only the initial condition should be declared and which is returned as a final result.

```
SELECT
    idx, time, category,
    weighted_density(distance, 10000) AS wd -- !!
FROM my_table
GROUP BY idx, time, category  
ORDER BY idx, time, category;

 idx |        time         | category |         wd          
-----+---------------------+----------+---------------------
   1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | class_a  |   0.476331421206002
   1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | class_b  |   0.968750868953701
   1 | 2017-01-01 00:13:00 | class_a  |    0.69665860026144
   1 | 2017-01-01 00:13:00 | class_b  |   0.952383202706387
   2 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | class_a  | 0.00519142111518706
   2 | 2017-01-27 21:07:00 | class_b  |   0.893107967346503
(6 rows)
```

I am not sure I have correctly read your intentions, however my remarks should put you on the right path.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out that the state needs to be carried along. I got it working now; will update my question with the solution I came up with. Thanks a lot, mate!